# Override method only for some template types

Tags: c++, sfinae, overriding

I have a base class with a default implementation of a virtual method:

```
class Base{
public:
   virtual void Method(){ /* Default implementation */ } 
}
```

and a template derived class:

```
template <typename T>
class Derived: public Base {
  ...
```

I'd need to override Base::Method only if T is copy-constructible. I've tried with something SFINAE-like:

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value, void>::type  Method(){ /* Override implemetation */ }
```

but when T is not copy-constructible I get this error:

```
error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
```

so I think the syntax is wrong. Is there a way to achieve what I need? Thanks.

Comment: `Method` is not virtual. You either contradict yourself, or you typed the code sample on the fly. Either way it's not good. Please take the time to make your question consistent before hitting submit.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I typed a simplified version of my code for the sake of clarity and I omitted/forgot some details. Now Method is virtual.

Comment: The answer of the original question linked by StoryTeller works perfectly also for me. Sorry for the duplicate, I searched before posting but I didn't find that one.

Answer (score -2):

This is from http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/

> First, you should understand that if you do not declare a copy 
>   constructor, the compiler gives you one implicitly. The implicit  copy
>   constructor does a member-wise copy of the source object.

So you don't need to worry about T having a copy constructor as long as it's not a primitive.

Comment: have... you read the question?

Comment: Unless of course the copy c'tor is deleted, and/or the type is only movable.

Comment: How would you delete an implicit constructor?

Comment: By explicitly defining a move c'tor for one.

Comment: Yes, you're right